# Is there a Data Structure in C++ that can automatically deque on reaching a specified size threshold?

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

I am looking for an existing implementation of a queue which will build up to a specified size, then if enqueued more elements, deque the last element before inserting the new one thereby maintaining its size always <= specified size.

I know this is pretty easy to implement myself with `std::list`, but I am just curious to know if there is already a data structure that exists like this in C++?

Comment: No, but you could make one fairly easily.

Comment: Its even easier to implement by wrapping a `std::list<>` or `std::deque<>`. There is no reason to reinvent that low-level wheel.

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah I know I can do it easily. when I said linked list I meant std::list. I was just curious to know if such a thing already exist as at least for my project it is being used very frequently.

Comment: @VivekVK I don't believe there is. Maybe `boost` has something already canned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a "circular_buffer" implementation in the boost library. (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html) for full documentation).

Quoting from the documentation:

> The `circular_buffer` is especially designed to provide fixed capacity storage. When its capacity is exhausted, newly inserted elements will cause elements to be overwritten, either at the beginning or end of the buffer (depending on what insert operation is used).

I think that's what you're looking for...

Comment: Thank you. On overview, it looks exactly what I wanted.